# Execute two commands in a row using one SSH object via paramiko

Tags: paramiko

How can I use one SSH object to execute two commands one after the other? can I use the ";" between the commands when sending them?
i.e : stdout = ssh.exec_command('command1';'command2')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not

```
ssh.exec_command('command1' ; 'command2')
```

Should be

```
ssh.exec_command('command1 ; command2')
```